# Python: How to split a string by phrase from right to left (first occurrence only)

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

Is it possible to split a string on a phrase (potentially more than one word) in Python 3 from right to left (first occurrence only)?

Currently I'm able to split a string based on a list of phrases but I have an edge case in that if more than one of those specified phrases occurs in the string then it splits on both.

**The problem**

Given a sample CSV containing the following:

| SENTENCES |  |
| --- | --- |
| THIS IS SENTENCE THREE | 1 |
| THIS IS SENTENCE TWO | 2 |
| I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO TWO | 3 |

And my code which opens a CSV, loops through each row, and then looks to split out specified phrases:

```py
import re
import csv

def split_phrase(string):
    phrases = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
    print(f'Raw: {string}')
    split_phrase = '' # Only needed for testing purposes to prevent error on output
    for phrase in phrases:
        if phrase in string:
            list = re.split(f'\\b({phrase})\\b', string)
            print(f'Split: {list}')
            sentence = list[0]
            split_phrase = list[1]
            print(f'Phrase: {split_phrase}')

    return sentence, split_phrase

input_dir = 'input1/'
output_dir = 'output1/'
filename = 'demo.csv'

with open(input_dir + filename, 'r') as input_csv:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(input_csv)
    data = list(csv_reader)
    input_csv.close()

    for row in data[1:]: # Ignore the header row
        sentence = row[0] # First column
        sentence = split_phrase(sentence) # Split out specified phrase
```

I get the following output:

```
$ python3 demo.py
Raw: THIS IS SENTENCE THREE
Split: ['THIS IS SENTENCE ', 'THREE', '']
Phrase: THREE
Raw: THIS IS SENTENCE TWO
Split: ['THIS IS SENTENCE ', 'TWO', '']
Phrase: TWO
Raw: I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO TWO
Split: ['I CONTAIN ', 'ONE', ' BUT ALSO TWO']
Phrase: ONE
Split: ['I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO ', 'TWO', '']
Phrase: TWO
```

**NOTE:** The last sentence is processed by the for loop twice due to it containing two of the phrases in the phrase list.

**Desired outcome**

I know that of the listed phrases to split out it will always be the last one on the right. So I'd like to grab **only the first occurrence from right to left**.

**NOTE:** A "phrase" can contain one or more words.

Is this possible? And if so, how may I achieve it?

Comment: Based on your update `words => phrases` I have edited my answer.

Comment: It is not clear to me but for the last sample sentence, do you want *both* splits (ONE and TWO) or just the split on TWO since that's the rightmost?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Just the split on TWO because it's the rightmost.

Comment: Then any of the answers below should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this by using `string.rfind()` to search from the end of the string, and iterating through the list of possible phrases. There may be better ways to do this that do not iterate, but this is the best I've found.

```
one = "THIS IS SENTENCE THREE"
two = "THIS IS SENTENCE TWO"
three = "I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO TWO"
four = "I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO TWO AND SOME MORE TEXT"
phrases = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']

def find_words(phrases, string):
    i = -1
    p = ""
    for phrase in phrases:
        newI = string.rfind(phrase)
        if newI > i:
            i = newI
            p = phrase
    return (string[:i], string[i:i+len(p)], string[i+len(p)::])

print(find_words(phrases, one))
print(find_words(phrases, two))
print(find_words(phrases, three))
print(find_words(phrases, four))
```

Output:

```
('THIS IS SENTENCE ', 'THREE', '')
('THIS IS SENTENCE ', 'TWO', '')
('I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO ', 'TWO', '')
('I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO ', 'TWO', ' AND SOME MORE TEXT')
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `string.rfind()`. In trying to understand it, can you explain what `string[:i]` and `string[i::]` are? I've just not seen that syntax before.

Comment: I've got it now. `[Start : Stop : Steps]`. So `string[i::]` is slicing the string starting from the index that `rfind()` returns with no stop or steps.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond but yes, that is correct. If your question is answered, please be sure to mark the solution.

Comment: Thanks @LaytonGB. I've marked this as the correct answer. One extra question though, rather than set the phrase as `string[i::]`, how can I set the slice stop to the length of the word, just in case there's anything else after it?

Comment: I've edited my post to your comments requirements. Be sure not to confuse the `p` and `phrase` variables which were altered since the last answer version. Best of luck!

Comment: Superb! You know your Python! :) That adds in an extra safety net. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it will work if you use "rsplit()" instead of "split()"

Comment: OP is using `re.split`. `re.rsplit` does not exist.

Comment: OP is reaching for the wrong tool in the first place it looks like.  Assuming we understand their problem, there is no reason to use `re.split`.

Comment: Looking at `rsplit()` it doesn't look like it accepts a regular expression? I need to pass in a regular expression to identify the word to split out.

Comment: Nevermind, I think it was unclear to me at first that they *only* want to split on specific words.

Comment: I'm open to other ways of getting to the desired outcome. I just started using `re.split()` for the regular expression but my list of words are known. They are greater than listed here for the demo but still known. I just need to ensure that it's a separate word and not part of another word. i.e. `ONE` should match but not `SOMEONE`. That's why I used a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

The key, I think, is to split into words, then reverse that list, then search for the all the hits and pick the lowest number:

```
def split_word(string):
    words = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']
    search = string.split()
    rsearch = list(reversed(search))
    locs = [rsearch.index(w) for w in words if w in rsearch]
    if not locs:
        return None
    target = len(search) - min(locs) - 1
    return ' '.join(search[0:target]), search[target], ' '.join(search[target+1:])

print(split_word("THIS IS SENTENCE THREE"))
print(split_word("THIS IS SENTENCE TWO"))
print(split_word("I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO TWO"))
```

Output:

```
('THIS IS SENTENCE', 'THREE', '')
('THIS IS SENTENCE', 'TWO', '')
('I CONTAIN ONE BUT ALSO', 'TWO', '')
```

Comment: Interesting approach. What if the 'word' to search for was made up of two words? I used the term 'word' for the example here but in hindsight that may have been misleading. Potentially it's also a phrase. More of a set string.

Comment: @Ian That's very misleading yes.

Comment: I'll update the example to use 'phrase' instead of 'word'. They are still _items_ in a list however.